# The remote name could not be resolved: 'testapi.internet.bs'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

how to get domain availibilty ? im using this code but getting error saying  -  "The
   remote name could not be resolved: 'testapi.internet.bs'"
and  -url is not getting any output 
 https://testapi.internet.bs/Domain/Check?ApiKey=test123&Password=test123&Domain=google.com

```
 public StreamReader URLServerRequest(string url)
                    {
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                    return stream;
                    }
```

Comment: I know those are only test credentials but you should be careful including them in your post. I'd also question why you're sending a password/apikey as a querystring parameter.. do you think this approach is secure?

Comment: but this is the format to send password . do u know any other web apis by which we can get domain availibility? @DGibbs

Comment: Then it's a poor API... Use `HttpWebResponse` instead of a `StreamReader` and check the response status code.

Comment: response status code is different and domain availibility is different . will httpwebresponse provide domain availibility ?

Comment: i don't want status code . i just want that domain is available or not . can we find out domain is available or not through httpwebresponse @DGibbs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73336/discussion-between-krishna-mohan-and-dgibbs).

Comment: OH... you want to read the domain availability from the API response, my understanding was that you wanted to check if the domain was accessible, not that it was available to register. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below example, it's not perfect but demonstrates what you need to do to read the `status` value from the response. You should check whether the API supports returning a structured response such as JSON data.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string domainAvailability = GetDomainAvailability("https://testapi.internet.bs/Domain/Check?ApiKey=testapi&Password=testpass&Domain=google.com");
    Console.WriteLine(domainAvailability);
    Console.Read();
}

public static string GetDomainAvailability(string url)
{
    string content = string.Empty;
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        content = wc.DownloadString(url);
    }

    string[] responseValues = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
    {
        responseValues = content.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
    else
    {
        return "empty response";
    }

    if (responseValues.Any(x => x.Contains("status=")))
    {
        return responseValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains("status=")).Split('=')[1];
    }
    else
    {
        return "status parameter not found";
    }
}
```

This returns `UNAVAILABLE` for your example